# No procedure/function/signature

Tags: oracle, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I am relatively new at using stored procedures and I have really run up aganst the wall. I am receiving the following error message using the Spring JdbcTemplate. My dev environment is Xubuntu, jdk 1.8.

### The stack trace is:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Unable to determine the correct call signature - no procedure/function/signature for 'PROCONEINPARAMETER'
  at org.springframework.jdbc.core.metadata.GenericCallMetaDataProvider.processProcedureColumns(GenericCallMetaDataProvider.java:347)
  at org.springframework.jdbc.core.metadata.GenericCallMetaDataProvider.initializeWithProcedureColumnMetaData(GenericCallMetaDataProvider.java:112)
  at org.springframework.jdbc.core.metadata.CallMetaDataProviderFactory$1.processMetaData(CallMetaDataProviderFactory.java:133)
  at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:299)
  at org.springframework.jdbc.core.metadata.CallMetaDataProviderFactory.createMetaDataProvider(CallMetaDataProviderFactory.java:73)
  at org.springframework.jdbc.core.metadata.CallMetaDataContext.initializeMetaData(CallMetaDataContext.java:286)
  at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.AbstractJdbcCall.compileInternal(AbstractJdbcCall.java:303)
  at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.AbstractJdbcCall.compile(AbstractJdbcCall.java:288)
  at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.AbstractJdbcCall.checkCompiled(AbstractJdbcCall.java:348)
  at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.AbstractJdbcCall.doExecute(AbstractJdbcCall.java:375)
  at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcCall.executeFunction(SimpleJdbcCall.java:153)
  at test.jdbc.StringDao.executeProcOneINParameter(StringDao.java:21)
  at test.jdbc.SimpleJdbcTest.main(SimpleJdbcTest.java:15)
```

### Code:

#### SimpleJdbc.java

```
package test.jdbc;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;  
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;  
public class SimpleJdbcTest {



    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        ApplicationContext ctx=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");  
           StringDao dao=(StringDao)ctx.getBean("edao");  
        String request = new String(" Wow, this works!");

        String response = dao.executeProcOneINParameter(request);  
        if (response != null && !response.equals(new String())) {
            System.out.println("stored proc worked: "+ response);

        } else {
            System.err.println("stored proc did not work.");
        }
    }  

}
```

#### StringDao.java

```
package test.jdbc;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcCall;

public class StringDao {

    private static final String PROC_NAME = "PROCONEINPARAMETER";
    private static final String CAT_NAME = "LISTENER";
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public void setJdbcTemplate(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
    }

    public String executeProcOneINParameter(String callParam){
        SimpleJdbcCall jdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate)
                .withCatalogName(CAT_NAME)
                .withProcedureName(PROC_NAME);

        return jdbcCall.executeFunction(String.class, callParam);
    }

}
```

#### Stored Proc:

```
PROCONEINPARAMETER

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE procOneINParameter(param1 IN VARCHAR2)
IS
BEGIN

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Hello World IN parameter ' || param1);

END;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to call a procedure, not a function. But you are calling it via the [`executeFunction()`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/simple/SimpleJdbcCall.html#executeFunction-java.lang.Class-java.lang.Object...-) method, and specifying a return type of `String`.

You need to use [`execute()`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/simple/SimpleJdbcCall.html#execute-java.lang.Object...-) instead, still passing the procedure argument, but without the return type (since there isn't one from a procedure):

```
Map<String,Object> out = jdbcCall.execute(callParam);
```

Your procedure doesn't have any OUT parameters either so `out` will be empty.

Comment: even though it was a red herring, it lead me to the right answer.

Answer (score 4):

Aside from the problems that @Alex posted, and I corrected, the final problem was the following:

```
static final String PROC_NAME = "PROCONEINPARAMETER";
private static final String CAT_NAME = "LISTENER";

…..
SimpleJdbcCall jdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate)
            .withCatalogName(CAT_NAME)
            .withProcedureName(PROC_NAME);
```

instead of:

```
SimpleJdbcCall jdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate)
            .withSchemaName(CAT_NAME)
            .withProcedureName(PROC_NAME);
```

Obviously, there was no way for anyone to know that I was using catalog and schema name interchangeably.

Answer (score 0):

Had similar problem.

Issue was : Schema Name was in uppercase, so it was taking double quotes.
eg : SchemaName was ABCD, while executing postgres was expecting "ABCD".

Resolution : converted schema name to lowercase.